# Не могу ограничить скорость скачивания файлов

Tags: php, файлы, php7, download

```
<?php

// local file that should be send to the client

$local_file = 'test-file.zip';

// filename that the user gets as default

$download_file = 'your-download-name.zip';

// set the download rate limit (=> 20,5 kb/s)

$download_rate = 20.5;

if (file_exists($local_file) && is_file($local_file)) {

// send headers

header('Cache-control: private');
header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($local_file));
header('Content-Disposition: filename=' . $download_file);

// flush content

flush();

// open file stream

$file = fopen($local_file, "r");
while (!feof($file)) {

    // send the current file part to the browser

    print fread($file, round($download_rate * 1024));

    // flush the content to the browser

    flush();

    // sleep one second

    sleep(1);
}

// close file stream

fclose($file);
}
else {
die('Error: The file ' . $local_file . ' does not exist!');
 ?>
```

К примеру с использованием данного скрипта скорость загрузки почему то 8кб/c, даже если в переменной download rate будет 1000. Почему так? PHP7.

**Прошу прощения забыл добавить что файл расположен на удаленном сервере, я проверил с локальными всё нормально, но почему с удаленными так себя ведёт?**

Comment: какого размера файл, какие ограничения в том окружении, где запускается скрипт? может быть 8 кбит - это некий верхний порог, выставленный другим приложением или конфигом в вашей инфраструктуре.

Comment: @Lexx918, Нет, в php.ini всё нормально, на Apache тоже, скрипт запускается без дополнительных конфигов...